# Null object reference SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android

I get this error:

> Process: com.mycompany.myngdroidapp, PID: 16170
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference

I wrote this code

**ContextClass:**

```
package com.ngdroidapp;

import android.content.Context;

import istanbul.gamelab.ngdroid.base.BaseActivity;
import istanbul.gamelab.ngdroid.base.BaseCanvas;

public class ContextClass
{
    public static Context context;
    public static BaseActivity activity;

    public static void setContext(Context Ncontext) {
        context = Ncontext;
    }

    public static  Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public static void setActivity(BaseActivity activity) { ContextClass.activity = activity; }

    public static BaseActivity getActivity() { return activity; }
}
```

**MenuCanvas:**

```
public Context getApplicationContext() {
        return context;
    }

    SharedPreferences mSharedPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("veriTabani", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor mPrefsEditor = mSharedPrefs.edit();
            int seviye = mSharedPrefs.getInt("seviye", 0);
            mPrefsEditor.putInt("seviye", ++seviye);
            mPrefsEditor.commit();
```

Comment: your `context` object is null. Make sure you're initializing the object correctly.

Comment: can you look at this one more time?

Comment: `context` is null. Declaring it does not assign it a value.

Comment: so how can I assign value?

Comment: look at `getApplicationContext()` for android it should return the `context` for you

Comment: please take a look once more updated

Answer (score 0):

`context` has not been initialized. It's null. You can get the context with `getApplicationContext()` if within an `Activity` or `Service`, you can get the context with `getContext()` if it's inside a `Fragment`. Or pass it as a parameter to a method or constructor wherever else those methods are defined.

Comment: No, it has not to be done that way. Can you provide the entire class code? So we can edit it for you?

Comment: the `MenuContext` is class is in which file?

Comment: /app/java/com/ngdroidapp/MenuCanvas

Answer (score 0):

On Android, you can cast Activity to Context. So you can use the Android Activity of your app where you need the context. On NgdroidApp, the activity is a public member of the root (NgApp class). If you need to reach the activity from your MenuCanvas, you can write:

```
SharedPreferences mSharedPrefs = root.activity.getSharedPreferences("veriTabani", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you haven't initialized the Context.

Initialize it before using like:

```
context = getApplicationContext();
```

or

```
context = YourActivityName.this;
```

or

```
context = this;
```